# “The most something” vs. “most something”

Tags: articles, superlatives

> It might be Procter & Gamble that makes **the** most washing powders.

#### Do we need “the” here?

It seems to me that the sentence means the number of washing powder trademarks offered by Procter & Gamble – not superior properties of these washing powders, and therefore “the” is redundant here.

Source: “Objective IELTS Advanced” ("Grammar folder" - So the sentence comes without context.)

Comment: What is that particular lesson covering, where the sentence is found?

Comment: @J.R. It looks to be [page 139 here](http://dl.delinglish.com/Objective%20IELTS%20Advanced.%20Students%20Book%20.pdf) reviewing Cleft Sentences (page 23).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [most/most of/ the most of](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5907/most-most-of-the-most-of)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### “The most” means a plurality, and “most” means the majority

In your example,

> - “the most washing powders”

Means nobody else makes more washing powders — they are the #1-ranked company.

For every 100 packages that are sold, they sell the highest number.

> - “most washing powders”

.. means they make the majority of all of them.   Nobody else makes a lot.

For every 100 packages that are sold, they sell at least 51 of them.

#### The dictionary says:

> Most is used to form the superlative of many adjectives and adverbs:
>
> - Joanne is ***the most*** intelligent person I know.
>
> Most also means almost all:
>
> - I like ***most*** vegetables.
>     — [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/most)