# Question about "most" usage and meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage, usage, superlatives

I want to ask about a particular usage of the "most" word.

When I say (talking about YouTube videos for e.g.):

> Videos with most views

does it convey the meaning that those videos have views more than others? More specifically, **does it mean the same as**:

> Videos with largest numbers of views. If we create a list of all videos, these videos will come at the top of the list.

?

If not, how to use most to convey that meaning? or what are "most" alternatives?

How would a native express the meaning of the second quote above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are "most" and "the most" the same?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18571/are-most-and-the-most-the-same) See also [most/most of/ the most of](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5907/most-most-of-the-most-of)

Comment: I checked these questions but they don't answer my question

Comment: Oh, well in that case I simply don't understand your question. Note that idiomatically (maybe *grammatically*, I dunno), ***These are the videos with [the] most views*** is valid with or without the article. But *These are the videos with **the largest number[s]** of views* is NOT valid without that highlighted article (opinions may differ as regards whether ***numbers*** should be pluralised, and/or whether this choice could affect the meaning or syntactic structure).

Comment: The potentially duplicate question has a determiner before "most" in its examples. I also believe "most" has a slightly different meaning there.